# Add default value before each encrypted value in proguard

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

When i add my .aar file into main project, it conflict with other .aar file with error a.a found in other module

To resolve this, i think i need to add value prefix before each encrypted value, **like myArr.a.a** to avoid confict, i try some code on stack overflow, but not work.

Can anyone help me with any solution?